# Spark Streaming UpdateStateByKey in an infinite loop?

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, spark-streaming

I have the following code which joins two streams from Kafka:

```
val joinViewClickDstream = newViewDstream.fullOuterJoin(newClickDstream).map { elem =>
  (elem._1, (elem._2._1.getOrElse(Event(0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L)), elem._2._2.getOrElse(Event(0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L))))
}.updateStateByKey(updateState)
```

and the following test update function:

```
def updateState(newValues: Seq[(Event,Event)], state: Option[(Event,Event)]): Option[(Event, Event)] = {
    Some((Event(0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L), Event(0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L,0,0L)))
}
```

As you can see I simple return a new empty state as the updated state. However when run this code and filter for a specific key to see what happens, that key gets printed in what looks like an infinite loop. Here is the code:

```
joinViewClickDstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
        val avroMessage = convertToAvroMessage(message)
        val trackingId = avroMessage.get("TrackingId").toString
        if (trackingId.contains("MyUserId")) {
          println(avroMessage)
        }
```

If i don't use updateStateByKey everything I print looks normal, but with the updateStateByKey function, my userid gets printed indefinitely. Have anyone else seen this behaviour?

P.S: I am using Spark 1.5.2, and can't switch to 1.6 as our cluster won't get upgraded yet.

Edit: Expected output is

```
{"myuserid", result{....}}
```

printed just once.

Instead I see:

```
{"myuserid", result{....}}
{"myuserid", result{....}}
{"myuserid", result{....}}
{"myuserid", result{....}}
{"myuserid", result{....}}
....
```

printed indefinitely

Comment: I don't get it. Could you give examples about what's the output and what's the expected values? I don't find any codes use `rdd`, either.

Comment: Sorry, have added some detail on the expected output. The newViewDstream and newClickDstream are two Dstream objects created from KafkaUtils.createDirectStream

Comment: So it outputs every batch. Right? It's expected. It outputs all history data. If you want to output only the new date, you need to filter them by yourself.

Comment: What happens is that when I create one message with the key "myuserid" and send to the kafka cluster, the above code will print the same message what appears to be an infinite amount of times (have let it run for 2 hours). Is this expected? (When I use mapWithState it acts as expected, but can't use that yet on our cluster)

Comment: Yep, updateStateByKey always processes the all states. That's why `mapWithState` is introduced.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this!